# Render HTML tags as HTML when read through XML RSS feed Sharepoint 2013

Tags: html, xml, xslt, sharepoint, rss

There have been similar questions but none working with SharePoint and the XSL editor.

I have an RSS feed which is pulling in article titles, along with accompanying html tags as shown below:

`<i>Wall Street Journal</i> Article on Competition in the Dental Industry`

I would like to have those `<i>` (and any other HTML tags) be read as HTML, not text..i.e an end result of:

```
Wall Street Journal Article on Competition in the Dental Industry
```

I can read and semi-reverse engineer XML, but writing it is another story.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

A sample of my code where I think the changes is needed, below:

```
<xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
            <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
            <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                <div class="item link-item" >
                        <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        </a>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                </div>                            
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The key to this issue is the `disable-output-escaping` attribute.  I was correct about the location of the issue.  Below is my adjusted code.  Notice lines 10-15

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:param name="Rows"/>
<xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
  <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
  <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
  <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
  <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
    <div class="item link-item" >
      <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
          <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="title"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </a>
      <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
        <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
          <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
        <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
          <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<div class="description">
  <h4 class="ms-rteElement-H4B">
    <span class="ms-rteStyle-Emphasis">
      <br></br>View More Articles&#160;<img alt="more-icon-1.png" src="/BHiveImageGallery/Stock-Images/more-icon-1.png"/>
    </span>
    <span class="ms-rteStyle-Emphasis"> </span>
  </h4>
</div>
```

My full code is too long and formatted too uniquely to get it to display as I want in the window.  It is 3/20/2015 right now, if you message me within the next 5 years i'll be able to send you the code, beyond that, no guarantees haha.

Generally though I used the SharePoint 2013 standard RSS viewer webpart code, and only modified the piece above